# Anylogic: How to produce various Products?

Tags: model, simulation, anylogic

I would like to simulate a model in which 6 different product variants are produced (A,B,C,D,E,F). Now the products should be produced in a specific order (production plan), so that for example A is produced 100times and then the source starts to fire with B and so on...

- **How can I model the different product variations?**
- **And how can I model that the source produces a specific amount of a variation and then produces the next variation and so on and then repeats this progress endless?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of explanation with incomplete information, so i can just give you a guideline...

the different product variations can be either defined as different agents if they are very different or they can be defined though a parameter in your agent for instance called productType that is different for every product variant (if they are not that different)

to produce a specific amount the simplest way, use arrivals defined by inject function in your sources and use an event with a rate for the product to arrive using source.inject()... then in the event you can create conditions, counting the products that have been injected and when you reach the limit, you just start injecting into a different source... having a separate source for each product would be the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I' m also a newbie in Anylogic, so it's just an idea or suggestion:

Would it be possible for the `source` to use a `database` and thus create *products* (own agent type) with the appropriate *ProductVariantID*.
For that it is necessary:

- Previously created `agent type` (Let's call the agent type "Product Agent") for the products. Thus, all products have properties through parameters/variables/etc., which can be used, to represent the product variant
- created `database` used to determine the production plan (order and amount of the different products).

So, the `source` creates *products* of type "Product Agent" with a certain *ProductVariantID* according to the information out of `database`. But unfortunately I don't know exactly, how to connect `source` and `database`. Maybe there's another person who can explain that step.